# A question about matrix product with multiple dimensions in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Studying the code related to a paper, I'm trying to understand the following thing:

Let's consider a `tf.tensor` called `x` of shape `(4, 64, 5, 5, 5)` and the following array:

> p

```
array([[[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

with shape `(5,5,5)`.

Now what does it mean to compute the operation `x @ p` ? Is this the matrix product between `x` and `p`. If yes, how should I interpret it having multiple dimensions?

Comment: From [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), *If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly*. So your `x` is `4 x 64 x 5` matrices, your `p` is `1 x 1 x 5` matrices, each is a `5 x 5` matrix.

Comment: 'each is a 5x5 matrix' but I don't understand which are the elements then? So x will be a 5x5 matrix with shape 4x64x5? I don't understand sorry

Comment: no `x` has `4 x 64 x 5` matrices, each is `5 x 5`, similarly `p` is `1 x 1 x 5 = 5` matrices. `x @ p` is like `x[i,j,k] @ p[k]`.

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow dcumentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) says that the operator `@` just call the method `tf.matmul`, so it is just the matrix multiplication. For normal matrices, using index notation, this is just (I will use Latex notation):

```
$$
\sum_{b} A_{ab} B_{bd} = C_{ad}
$$
```

For a range larger than 2, this operation is described as follows:

```
$$
\sum_{i} A_{abc...ni} B_{abc...im} = C_{abc...nm}
$$
```

So in your example, we have `x.shape = (4, 64, 5, 5, 5)` and `p.shape = (5, 5, 5)`, which means that the result is a tensor of the shape `(4, 64, 5, 5, 5)`. It performs `4 x 64 x 5 = 5120` matrix multiplications of the form `(5,5)@(5,5)`.

To be more precise, if I call `A = x@p`, you can check that the value of `A[i, j, k]` will be equal to `x[i, j, k] @ p[k]`.